# How can i set the Mac Colorful Loading Cursor to an NSImageView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nscursor

I know how to set a NSCursor when the mouse enters the NSImageView, but I can't find a way to set this particular cursor:
[image]

How can I set this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spinning wait cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel) is a Mac OS X system cursor that indicates an application is not responding to system events. This is NOT a good thing. Experienced users that see this cursor will think that your application has hung and will force quit it.

> How can I set this one?

Don't respond to system events and the system will display it for you… [\humor]